# Jquery post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a jquery post method that sends name , password and email to register.php

```
function postData()
{
    thisBtn = $(this); 
    parent = $(this).parent(); 
    name = parent.data('name'); 
    password = parent.data('password'); 
    email =parent.data('email');
    $.post('register.php', {name: (name), password: (password), email: (email)},     function(data) ;
    parent.next('#message').html(data);
}
```

The button that performs the function onclick:

```
<button onclick = 'postData()' class='regular' name='save'>
```

However nothing seems to be happening when the button is cicked

Comment: How are you binding your onclick event?

Comment: First of all, start with some basic debugging.  Use something like Firebug and put breakpoints in the code to see what actually _is_ happening.  (As opposed to just saying that nothing seems to be happening.)  Does the function actually get called?  If so, what are the variables in the function being set to?  Does it get as far as the call to `$.post()`?  What are the states of the objects at that time?  You need to do some basic debugging here to help us help you.  Otherwise, there's just too much potentially wrong with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you call `postData` with no associated object, inside the function `this` is the same as `window` so none of the elements you access are the ones you expect.

Don't use [intrinsic event attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3), bind your handlers using JavaScript. Since you are already using jQuery you should use [the methods it provides for that](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Comment: im not sure the function knows where to find name password email

Answer (score 1):

This syntax looks mangled

```
$.post('register.php', {name: (name), password: (password), email: (email)},     function(data) ;
    parent.next('#message').html(data);
// no {} for function, no closing ) for $post, and premature ;
```

Try

```
$.post('register.php', {name: (name), password: (password), email: (email)}, function(data) {
    parent.next('#message').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Indeed, I wonder if "nothing seems to be happening" is another way of saying that the browser is throwing a JavaScript error and the OP doesn't know where to look for those.

Comment: Even then, "parent" isn't a jQuery object, so it won't have an associated next() function to call.  (Or rather, $(this) is meaningless, so parent() will probably be an empty jQuery object)

Comment: @Dave Hmm, are you sure? `$(this).parent();` returns jQuery.. are you saying it's out of scope?

Comment: im not sure the function knows what name, password, email is

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options ...

either pass and object in the onclick :

```
<button onclick='postData(this)' class='regular' name='save'>
```

or attach the click handler using jQuery - preferred method when using jQuery :

```
$('input[name="save"]').click(function() {
   // your post code here
}};
```

there would then be no need for the `onclick='postData(this)'`

Answer (score 0):

**Send the post data like this you will get proper output**

name = 'demo'; 
            password = '123456'; 
            email = 'demo@gmail.com';

```
      $.post('register.php',{ 'name': name, 'password': password, 'email': email},function(html){

                                alert(html);     
     },"html");
```

//register.php

echo $_POST['name'];

Comment: It's not necessary to put property names in strings when creating a data object for $.post, unless the name otherwise wouldn't be a valid javascript variable name (like 'names[]')

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to bind to the button click as well if you want things to work properly.  (EDIT: also, let's use a non-deprecated element)

```
<input type='button' class='regular' name='save' id='btnPost' value='Post' />
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnPost").on("click", function() {
        var thisBtn = $(this); 
        var parent = thisBtn.parent(); 
        // Replacing this by serializing the parent form -
        // not sure what parent.data is going to give without seeing the rest
        // of the html
        // name = parent.data('name'); 
        // password = parent.data('password'); 
        // email =parent.data('email');
        $.post('register.php', thisBtn.closest("form").serialize(),          
            function(data) {
                parent.next('#message').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var $this = $('id_of_button');
     $this.click(function(){
            //ajax logic here
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: url,
              data: data,//data to send to serverside
              success: success, //function to call on success
              dataType: dataType//datatype eg.text,json etc.
            });
     });
});
```